# Counting unique elements in a subdocument array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an subdocument that has an array of names. I want the number of unique names in the collection. A document looks like:

```
{name: "salesman",
 people: [{name: "Joe"}, {name: "Brian"}]}
```

I have run:

```
db.jobs.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$job.people"},
  {$group: {_id: "$job.people.name"}},
  {$group: {_id: null, total: {$sum: 1}}}
]);
```

This seems to work, but since there are a lot of unique names in the DB I don't have a very good way of verifying that it is correct, so I thought I would check here.

Is there a preferred method for counting the number of unique items in a subdocument array?

Comment: @JohnnyHK yes that is a much better way of doing it; you could make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of doing this is to use the [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct) function to get an array of the distinct values of the embedded `name` field, and then check its length.

In the shell:

```js
db.jobs.distinct('job.people.name').length
```

That's assuming the `job` subdocument level that you show in your code but not your example document is, in fact, there. Otherwise it would just be `'people.name'`.